Ruby on rails - I want a behavior, when validity is true, but validity is always true, as Required: false,
My issue is precisely this. I am using simple forms and one of my sections (one_liner), is not behaving as wanted. As it can be seen from the picture, the label should not hover, if nothing is inputted into the form, I achieve this in "full name" and "company name" by setting Required: True, because they ARE required to submit the form. However, the one_liner is not required and must not be required and as such it will always be valid. I added a minlength to try and invalidate it, when an input less than 1 character is inputted, but that only works when its in focus.
Image 1
Image 2
So my question is this: How do I make the label stay in place, and when something is written in the one_liner input field, the label floats?
I get the wanted behavior, visually, when I change the "&:valid ~ label" to "&invalid ~ label". This only works because, now I just reversed the playing field... Since the one_liner input field is always valid, the label will stay in place but this means I must never be valid, but I cannot submit the form if the one_liner isn't valid..


  &.required{
    &:focus ~ label,
    &:valid ~ label {
      color: map-get($foundation-palette, 'primary');
      top: 2px;
      left: 31px;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
  &.optional {
    &:focus ~ label,
    &:valid ~ label{
      // Styles for when the input is focused
      color: map-get($foundation-palette, 'primary');
      top: 2px;
      left: 31px;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
            = f.fields_for :settings, current_user.settings || current_user.build_settings do |settings_form|
              = settings_form.input :one_liner,
                      as: :string,
                      required: false,
                      placeholder: false,
                      label: t('.oneliner_placeholder'),
                      wrapper: :input_field_wrapper,
                      input_html: { class: 'secondary_form-control', minlength: "1" }



This only works because, now I just reversed the playing field... Since the one_liner input field is always valid, the label will stay in place but this means I must never be valid, but I cannot submit the form if the one_liner isn't valid..

As written its very hard to understand what your actual issue is here but I think you're expecting something completly unrealistic of the browsers built-in client-side form validation. They just handle the most basic of cases and if you want more sophisticated client side validations you need to use javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation
